# How to calculate the sound volume for the left ear and right ear based on the object position & velocity, player position & forward vector? (3D sound)

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, audio, game-engine

Please assume:

Minimum distance for 3D volume = 1.0;
Maximum distance for 3D volume = 100.0;

This is the declaration of the function:

An object can be a ball moving closer to the player.

```
void CalculateSoundVolume(Vec3 objectPosition, 
                          Vec3 objectVelocity, 
                          Vec3 userHead, 
                          Vec3 userFoward, 
                          float& leftEarVolume, 
                          float& rightEarVolume)  
{

}
```

Comment: Either use the builtin features that are most likely already doing the right thing or calculate it yourself using some basic physics knowledge. The first way will almost always be the better way.

Comment: I'm curious whether there are provisions in Unity to add a bit of delay rather than using volume for the stereo effect. It seems to me, using volume alone to achieve stereo is problematic, especially for far left or far right that leaves the opposite ear with very little volume (allowing other, ostensibly quieter sound to be heard when they should be masked). I've not used Unity yet.

Answer (score 2):

You may start to use this basic fact:

The speed of sound is the distance travelled per unit time by a sound wave as it propagates through an elastic medium. In dry air at 20 °C (68 °F), the speed of sound is 343 metres per second (1,125 ft/s; 1,235 km/h; 767 mph; 667 kn), or a kilometre in 2.91 s or a mile in 4.69 s.

The sound pressure level (SPL) decreases with doubling of the distance by (−)6 dB. The sound pressure falls 1/2 times (50%) of the sound pressure of the initial value. It drops with the ratio 1/r of the distance. The sound intensity level decreases with doubling of the distance by (−)6 dB.

To elaborate a basic model of propagation that will tell you what your player would hear in real life.